# Why when I unchecked DMA in Windows 7, the CPU usage was still very low?

Tags: computer-architecture

I am studying about PIO mode and DMA mode for accessing IO devices, and based on what I have read, in PIO mode the data transfer have to go through the CPU.

So I have unchecked DMA in Windows 7 (which I guess will enable PIO mode):

[image]

And I copied and pasted a large file to see the CPU usage, and the CPU usage was still very law (about 5%). Shouldn't PIO mode exhaust the CPU?

Comment: If this is a question about Windows specifically, then it is probably off-topic. But it seems like it's more general. Can you formulate it so that it applies to more general situations?

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of DMA is OK. But disk accesses are generally slow. So the CPU may spend is time on waiting for the disk to write the bytes on the disk, he is not stressed.
May be you can try to run something like CPU Burner that will stress the CPU and then measure the time to copy with/without DMA enabled.
Note that many things can interfere with your measurements, particularly HD caches.

Comment: I suspect the cache is the main thing here. Operating system buffer caches typically aren't "write-through", and if this was the only thing the machine was doing, the low CPU usage wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: I agree, the file size must be large. Obviously larger than the cache size. May be you can try with different sizes of the files to see what happens.